# Some questions with linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the infinite dimensional vector space of all polynomials $P(x)$ with real coefficients. Define a linear transformation $T:P \to P$ by $T(P(x))=P(x)+P'(x)$ for all polynomials $P(x)$ in $P$. Prove that T is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: Have you tried anything? For starters, do you know the definitions of 1-1 and onto, and have an idea of how one might check this?

Comment: It is generally impolite to ask others to solve your homework (or any other question you are trying to solve for whatever reason). Try to explain what you tried so far and what you are struggling with.

Comment: Think of a polynomial as a sequence of numbers, of which only a finite number are non-zero. Write out the expression for $TP$. Solve $TP=0$. Then solve $TP=Q$, where $Q$ is another polynomial.

Comment: I am struggling with proving onto part. The one-to-one part I think I am Ok, it requires two different polynomials to get different results after $T$. I think I should start supposing that $T$ is not onto and try to prove a contradiction. I think suppose $f(x)-g(x)\ne g'(x)$, then $f(x)-g(x)=h(x)=g'(x)$ but we can get $g(x)=xh(x)$, so $f(x)$ can be represented as a function, then is the contradiction, is this correct? It's just I am preparing for an exam but these questions don't have answers, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: You can compute an explicit polynomial $P$ that satisfies $TP = Q$. No need for any fancy stuff.

Comment: what is $P'(x)$ is it just $P(x)$ with one lower degree?

Comment: @user121819: No. If $P(x) = p_0+p_1x+...+p_n x^n$, what is the derivative?

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I agree with copper.hat. You can solve for polynomial *P* easily by computing each of its coefficient. Write down eqns to find coefficients of P you will get a system of linear equations. Notice that it is upper triangular and you are done :)